# I have created header component and i want to open drawer from there

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have created header component and i want to open drawer from header component from icon click, currently swipe is opening drawer. please help if anyone know what is the issue

this is my app js code where i created drawer navigator

```
<NavigationContainer>
          <Drawers.Navigator drawerContent={props => <Drawer {...props} />} >
            <Drawers.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  component={Home}
                  initialParams={({navigation}) => {
                    return{
                      headerTitle:() => <HomeHeader navigation={navigation}/>,
                    }
                  }}
                  
              />
            <Drawers.Screen
                name="Orders"
                component={Orders}
                
                
            />
             <Drawers.Screen
                name="Account"
                component={Account}
            />
            
        </Drawers.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

and this is my header component where i was trying to navigation.openDrawer

```
export default function HomeHeader({navigation}) {
    const openMenu = () => {
        navigation.openDrawer();
    }
    return (
        <View style={GlobalStyle.hheader} >
            <View style={GlobalStyle.mainMenu} >
                <Icon type="material" name="menu" size={26} color="black" onPress={openMenu} />
            </View>
            <View style={GlobalStyle.near} >
                <Text style={GlobalStyle.nTitle}>Your Location</Text>
                <Text style={GlobalStyle.nLocate}>Mehran Town <Icon   iconStyle={{ marginBottom:-1, }} name='chevron-down' size= {16}  type='font-awesome' color='#000' 
    /></Text>
            </View>
            
        </View>
    )
}
```

and finally draweritem code

```
<DrawerItem 
                        
                        label="Profile"
                        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Account')}}
                        labelStyle={{color: '#000', fontSize:15}}
                                                  
                        icon={() => (
                            <Icon 
                            name='account-circle'
                            type='material'
                            color='#4285F4'
                            size={18}
                            
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                <DrawerItem 
                        
                        label="Orders"
                        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Orders')}}
                        labelStyle={{color: '#000', fontSize:15}}
                        navigation={props.navigation}
                        icon={() => (
                            <Icon 
                            name='receipt'
                            type='material-icons'
                            color='#4285F4'
                            size={18}
                            
                            />
                        )}
                    />
         </View>
```

Comment: Where is the Drawers component coming from?

Comment: @ShamarYarde from draweritem code

Comment: @ShamarYarde from drawer.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think headerTitle is place for you return custom header menu.

My suggestion you can render customer header in each screen content and using `navigation.openDrawer();` or try create wrapper view for Drawer and render header first. Or create BaseScreen with your custom header and inheritance for each your screen. But headerTitle I don't think it work.

Comment: yeah its not working can you suggest a best and minimal way to do that, and can you share that code with me or link describing your suggestion i am new in native so i will be thankful to you :)

Comment: Ok like this your CustomHeader look good, let move `<HomeHeader navigation={navigation}/>` to your home screen, orders screen, account screen in the first element render and retry. Or you need find some design pattern for create CustomHeader on react navigation. I just render custom header in content screen like my suggestion. Ex: `<View> < HomeHeader navigation={navigation} /> {children}</View>` // this is code in render method on home screen

Comment: okay thanks i am still confused but i will figure it out. :)